# In Spring Security config Urls which are permitted for all are not accessable and redirecting to login

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

In the configuration below I think I have not done anything wrong. The Urls that I have allowed for all are redirecting me to login page. Same problem with users having role USER.

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/new/**", "/edit/**", "/create/**", "/save/**").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/", "/registration/**", "/view/**",).permitAll()
                
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .and()
                .logout().invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/loggingOut").permitAll();
    }
```

If you can provide any resource which can help to understand better. I am new to spring, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with your Role Hierarchy. Try this.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/new/**", "/edit/**", "/create/**", "/save/**").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/", "/registration/**", "/view/**",).permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
            .and()
            .logout().invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .clearAuthentication(true)
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/loggingOut").permitAll();
}
```

If this did not work please try with different combinations.
This [article](https://www.baeldung.com/role-and-privilege-for-spring-security-registration#role-hierarchy) explains the Role Hierarchy, It can help you.

Comment: Thanks for response. Changing the arrangement of role worked for me. I know this concept but made some mistakes.